# Example 1.44 In Rudin's Functional Analysis ("Exhaustion by Compact Sets")

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, compactness

In example 1.44, Rudin introduces the space $C(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subseteq \Bbb{R}^k$ is open. He claims that $\Omega$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets $\{K_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ such that $K_n \subseteq \text{int } K_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$. How does one prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $K_n = \left\{x \; :  \; d(x, \Omega^{c} ) \geq {1  \over n}, \|x\| \leq n \right\}$.

Comment: If $n<a<n+1$ then $K_n \subset \{x:d(x,\Omega^{c}) >a, \|x\| <a\}$ Use this to prove that $K_n$ is contained in the interior of $K_{n+1}$.